# PHP preg_match_all only date in string

Tags: preg-match-all

```
<img src="http://resim.domain.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/yenisafak_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />
<img src="http://resim.ihlassondakika.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/zaman_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />
<img src="http://resim.ihlassondakika.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/milliyet_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />
<img src="http://resim.ihlassondakika.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/hurriyet_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />
```

preg_match_all image and save my hosting path please help

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want the matching to do.

Comment: Dont we love it when first posters don't come back :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you would need to...

```
$str = '<img src="http://resim.domain.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/yenisafak_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />';
$str = '<img src="http://resim.ihlassondakika.com/Gazete/kucuk/03.04.2013/zaman_kucuk_030413.jpeg" width="96" height="126"  />'
```

Then you would need to use the preg_match to pull out the matches

```
preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $str, $matches)
```

After this you can echo or store your matches in the matches varible, for instance you could echo these out or store them one by one.

```
echo $matches[0]; // first one 

echo $matches[1]; // second match
```

To the save your matches you would need a loop but you could save one like this.

```
$myFile = "test.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $matches[0];);
fclose($fh);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If this is correct please mark correct as this is your first post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use preg_match_all, then I will assume that the input lines are all contained in one string, say $str.  If so, then the following may be used to pull out just the paths, removing the filenames, assuming that is what was meant.  (Sorry if I misunderstood that.)

```
$pattern="#img.+?src\s*=\s*\"(.*?)/[^/]+\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)#i";
$n = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    print $matches[1][$i] . "\n"; # or save
}
```

Anyway, hoping this helps at all.